# ..how to return a Task<List<Model>> via c# and .net 4.0?

Tags: c#, task

i want to return a Task <List> .
via c# and .net 4.0 vs2019.
don't useing asyns.

```
        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task  List<AccountList> task1 = new Task List<AccountList>(() => {
           using (var db1 = new SqlConnection(DbHelper.AccountConStr))        

            {
                string sql = "select * from  AccountList where UseFlag='1'";
                try
                {
                    IEnumerable<AccountList> lst = db1.Query<AccountList>(sql);
                    return lst.ToList();
                }
                catch
                {
                    return new List<AccountList>();
                }
            }
        });
        task1.Start();
        while (timeout > sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
        source.Cancel();
```

how to return a Task <List>

Comment: Your question is not that clear but you can return task based result using async await... please check the official doc for this via this link

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/async-and-await-in-c-sharp/

Comment: The example uses async

My environment is. Net 4.0. Async cannot be used

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you return a

`Task<List<AccountList>>`

i.e just return task1.

Then in the calling method as you do not have async/await, you can achieve the same thing by using Task.ContinueWith(...).  The stuff you want to do when the task resolves goes inside the ContinueWith.  Async / Await is just synatx sugar.